# Core Data interfering with UI only when fetching data

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm rather new to Core Data, having a play around recently and cannot figure out what's wrong here.

When I execute the following code, everything works fine and all UI elements and animations are good too:

```
- (void)fetchCoreData {
    [self showStatusBarWithStatus:@"Complete"];

    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

        NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [self.appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator];

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyData"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *coreDataObjects = [backgroundContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);


        self.coreDataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSManagedObject *object in coreDataObjects) {
            NSDictionary *d = [object dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"uniID",@"uListCount"]];
            [coreDataArray addObject:d];
        }


        [self deleteAllObjects:@"MyData" withContext:backgroundContext]; //Clear Core Data

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self showStatusBarWithStatus:@"Complete"];

        });

    });
}


- (void) deleteAllObjects: (NSString *) entityDescription withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context  {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityDescription inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
        [context deleteObject:managedObject];
    }
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error deleting %@ - error:%@",entityDescription,error);
    }

}
```

But when I remove the line `[self deleteAllObjects ...];` my UI elements begin to mess up. Animations aren't working as they should be, `alpha` properties not appearing as they should (they appear `0.5f` when they should be `1.0f`, or `1.0f` instead of `0.0f`. I also removed the delete function and added a new object to Core Data in its place; and the problem went away. It seems that unless I make a change to Core Data (delete or add entries) the problem persists.

I'm sure there's something I've missed out in terms of how I should be executing this in a background thread?

Comment: Note that the table view data source array should also only be modified on the main thread. You should build a temporary array first and then assign it to the table view array on the main thread.

Comment: Have also a look at the new managed object concurrency types and the `performBlock` method, which makes everything a lot easier. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html.

Comment: @MartinR Cheers for that, I didn't come across it when searching. Can something such as not modifying an array on the main thread cause UI issues such as this?

Comment: Your effects sound a bit strange, but if table view accesses that array while you are modifying it in the background, problems must occur. - Did that already solve your problem?

Comment: It did fix a couple of UI problems but some others persist. I'll definitely update the thread if I can figure this out.

Comment: Just a guess, if you have a fetched results controller, keep in mind that it's going to react to each adding/deletion and trying to update the UI as quick as he can, and most of the time especially with large set of data this is causing strange behavior in the UI. In this case, you have to resign the fetched controller to be delegate of the UI controller, then do the update and merge, then reassign as delegate back to normal.

Comment: @MartinR Turned out to be one function interfering with another (show animation and hide animation). Added a couple of booleans for mutual checks and everything seems fine now. I did learn a thing or two along the way though with Core Data, cheers!